# HTTP meta refresh keeps looping in older browsers

Tags: redirects, refresh

I added an HTTP meta refresh to my site like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://mysite.com">
```

but it seems that the browser keeps looping (refreshing) in older Firefox browsers, while in the new version (30.0) it doesn't.

Comment: Could you post an url example from where you're redirecting to mysite.com? Is it possible that mysite.com's homepage is also printing the same exact redirect metatag?

Comment: Aside: A meta refresh is not a 301 redirect.

Comment: what i am actually trying to do is this. For some reason Google indexed my pages as https. so when user searches for my pages in google search returns show up as https://mysite.com. So i added code from above into my index.html so when user clicks on google returned (wrongly) https://mysite.com it will redirect user to http://mysite.com. This solution worked fine in new version of firefox but not in older ones.

Comment: how would i add redirect inside actual html

Comment: The best you can do is to implement server side 301 redirects, these work better for users and for crawlers. What's your website stack? linux/windows? apache/iis/other? Are you able to implement server side redirects?

Comment: If you have the above code on all pages (including HTTP) then it will result in a _loop_. If it is not in the latest version of Firefox then I'd wager that the latest version of Fx is simply detecting this loop and breaking. This `meta` tag should only appear on pages when accessed over HTTPS, not HTTP. If you are limited to only HTML then this (or a JavaScript redirect) is all you can do. But, as Binarysurf suggests, this should really be handled by a 301 redirect _on the server_ - that is the only reliable way to tell Google about the correct URL.

Comment: It is iis server

Comment: I forgot to ask something else: what programming language are you using? .NET(C#, VB.NET, etc, which .NET framework version?), php, python? which IIS version?

Comment: when i go to iis manager help and about it doesn't give me version at all

Comment: i added the redirect so that works. Hopefully google will reindex pages in few days

Comment: actually this didn't work....maybe i can try to explain better..google is indexing my page   http://mysite.com/index.html as https://mysite.com so when user clicks on that link it shows not secured content which freaks users out. i try to do redirect on iis in file properties by typing re-direct path as http://mysite.com  but now the when user clicks on that link there is an error that "it is not redirecting properly"

Comment: @Stribor Maybe you can expand your question to include what you're interested in, based on the comments above, so it will be clearer for others.

Comment: workaround i desribed below by adding redirect works just fine. I want to know how to find exactly what pages is google indexing as https. I am worried that i would have to create duplicate of each of this pages and use this duplicates to redirect to until google reindex this. I also added canonnical links to head of each page. Hopefully in few days that will clear up this https referencing issue. I would be really interested to know why this is hapening. Other search engines index my pages just fine

Answer (score 1):

Looping is what I would expect.  Likely, the `HTTP` and `HTTPS` versions of your page are served from the same document root.  This means the same content is served to the visitor regardless of the HTTP protocol.

As a result, when someone visits `https://mysite.com` they are redirected to `http://mysite.com` which then redirects them again to `http://mysite.com`.  This creates the loop.

With `meta-refresh` there is no way to distinguish between `HTTP` and `HTTPS` links.

What you want to do is use `mod_rewrite` as I documented here

[Search for my web site returns HTTPS results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/64996/search-for-my-web-site-returns-https-results/65025?noredirect=1#comment70124_65025)

Comment: where do you place that snippet of code?.htacces?

Comment: That goes into an htaccess file in your to level directory.

Comment: no....it didnt work.....i added it into top level directory and when i click on one of the google returned results it still does same thing. by the way my .htaccess contain only the code you have in post you suggested above

Comment: by the way my web server is not apache ): it is iis

Comment: The strategy would be the same -- just different rules.  I don't handle IIS admin so don't have a ruleset to recommend.

Comment: if i go into iis manager anbd right click on the index.html and put redirect to http://mysite.com then when i enter it into url location or click on one of the google searches get error "server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete".

Comment: i found why....its gooing into loop because its redirecting to the same page.so i had to duplicate my index.html into something like index1.html and then redirect to http://mysite.index1.html and that worked

Comment: Yes that's what I said ... http://mysite.com which then redirects them again to http://mysite.com. This creates the loop.